# Add a delete button to the end of a table PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-delete

I have outputted the results of a MySQL table to an HTML table. In the last column, I want to add a delete option that deletes the a user. I can't seem to get it to work though it keeps calling the last row only.

```
<?php

require("connection.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM userdetail inner join usertype on userdetail.userType = usertype.userID";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$list = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $userID = $row['userID'];
    $userName = $row['userName'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $usertype = $row['userType'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $postalCode = $row['postalCode'];

    $list .= "<tr><td>".$userID."</td><td>".$userName."</td><td>".$usertype."</td><td>". $email."</td><td>". $address."</td><td>".$postalCode."</td><td><form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='remove' value='Remove'> </form></td></tr>";
}

if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    $sql = "DELETE * FROM userdetails WHERE userID = $userID ";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { 
        echo 'Contact Has Been Deleted';
    } else { 
        echo 'Deletion Failed';
    } 
}

?>


<html>
<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>User Type</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Postal Code</th>
</tr>
<?php echo $list;?>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing MySQL APIs, they do not mix. This `mysql_affected_rows()` is one. Change to `mysqli_affected_rows()`

Comment: Also, get rid of the `*` for the delete.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` including `mysqli_error($con);` - You're not checking for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$userID` was not in the scope of the remove body, initialize it before the `while` loop

```
<?php

require("connection.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM userdetail inner join usertype on userdetail.userType =     usertype.userID";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$userID = '';
$list = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$userID = $row['userID'];
$userName = $row['userName'];
$email = $row['email'];
$usertype = $row['userType'];
$address = $row['address'];
$postalCode = $row['postalCode'];

$list .= "<tr><td>".$userID."</td><td>".$userName."</td><td>".$usertype."</td><td>". $email."</td><td>". $address."</td><td>".$postalCode."</td><td><form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='remove' value='". $userID ."'> </form></td></tr>";
}

if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
echo $sql = "DELETE FROM userdetails WHERE userID = '".$_POST['remove']."' ";
$query = $con->query($sql);
if ($query == 1) { 
    echo 'Contact Has Been Deleted';
} else { 
    echo 'Deletion Failed';
} 
}

?>
```

Comment: You're doing the same mistake, just differently. This will fail.

Comment: The `*` for the delete query, that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Now, it's "sit and wait" and see what OP says ;-)

Comment: Hey I tried to initialize the $userID before the while loop but it does not work.

Comment: userID is your primary key?

Comment: Yup. It is my primary key

Comment: put the userID value in input field like i Edited

Comment: I changed it but it still telling me that deletion failed. Also i tried echoing out the $userID when I press the remove button. It always echo out the last row's userID no matter which row's remove button I pressed on

Comment: would u echo the $sql and see the query built has right userID

Comment: `echo $sql = "DELETE...` the echo should also not be in there. That should only be done for debugging purposes.

Comment: the echo show --> DELETE * FROM userdetails WHERE userID = 'Remove'

Comment: nope i changed the value of input value <input type='submit' name='remove' value='". $userID ."'>

Comment: Now the echo shows DELETE * FROM userdetails WHERE userID = '3'. Now is still not able to delete.

Comment: it may delete the row you click one

Comment: Yeah thanks it worked however the button name would be the userName... Is there any other way?

Comment: Well i added another <input type='hidden' name='name' value='$userID'> and changed the $sql = "DELETE FROM userdetail WHERE userID = '".$_POST['name']."' ";
And it worked the same way just that my button now is named as removed! Thank you for the help!